# Every Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

I am trying to prove that:

**Theorem.** Let $F$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $\mathcal{H}^{n}(F)=c_{n}^{-1}\text{vol}^{n}(F)$ where $c_{n}$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional ball of diameter $1$ and $\mathcal{H}^{n}$ is the $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

*Proof* (so far). Let $F$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $$\mathcal{H}^{n}(F)=\lim_{\delta\to0}\left(\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|U_{i}|^{n}:\{U_{i}\} \text{ is a } \delta\text{-cover of } F\right\}\right)$$

***I am not sure how to then show that the RHS is $c_{n}^{-1}\text{vol}^{n}(F)$.*** Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the Lebesgue measure (or volume) of a Borel set $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is
$$ m(F) := \inf\left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} m(B_j) : \text{$\{B_j\}$ is a collection of open balls such that $F \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} B_j$}\right\}. $$

Note that the measure of a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is constant multiple of the radius to the $n$-th power.  That is, if $B(x,r)$ is the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$, then
$$ m(B(x,r)) = c_j r^n, $$
where $c_n$ is the measure of a ball of radius 1.  For example, the measure of a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\pi r^2$, and the measure of a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$ (these formulae should, I hope, ring a bell).  This implies that
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} m(B_j) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} c_j r_j^n, $$
where $r_j$ is the radius of the $j$-th ball in the collection.  Observe that if $\{U_j\}$ is a $\delta$-cover of $F$, then for each $j$ we can find a ball $B_j = B(x_j, r_j)$ such that $U_j \subseteq B(x_j,r_j)$ and $r_j = |U_j|/2$.  That is, every $\delta$-cover corresponds to a $\delta$-cover by open balls.  Hence we have
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}_\delta^n(F)
  &= \inf\left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |U_j|^n : \text{$\{U_j\}$ is a $\delta$-cover of $F$} \right\} \\
  &= \inf\left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |B_j|^n : \text{$\{B_j:=B(x_j,r_j)\}$ covers $F$, $r_j < \frac{\delta}{2}$} \right\} \\
  &\ge \inf\left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} r_j^n : \text{$\{B_j:=B(x_j,r_j)\}$ covers $F$} \right\} \tag{$\ast$} \\
  &= \inf\left\{ c_n^{-1} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} c_n r_j^n : \text{$\{B_j:=B(x_j,r_j)\}$ covers $F$} \right\} \\
  &= c_n^{-1} \inf\left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} m(B_j) : \text{$\{B_j:=B(x_j,r_j)\}$ covers $F$} \right\} \\
  &= c_n^{-1} m(F),
\end{align}
where the inequality at $(\ast)$ follows from the fact that if $X\subseteq Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then $\inf(X) \ge \inf(Y)$ (the intuition is that the smallest thing in $Y$ could be the smallest thing in $X$, or it could be even smaller, as there are more things in $Y$).  Taking $\delta\to 0$, this implies that
$$ \mathcal{H}^n(F) = \lim_{\delta\to 0} \mathcal{H}^n_{\delta}(F) \ge c_n^{-1} m(F), $$
which is half of what we need to show.

The other inequality is (perhaps) a bit tricker.  First, note that if $m(F) = \infty$, we are done, so assume that $m(F) < \infty$.  I am now going to rely on some basic results about Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$, without proving them.  Fix some $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$.  There exists a collection of balls $\{B_j = B(x_j, r_j)\}$ such that

1. $F \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} B_j$,
2. $r_j < \frac{\delta}{2}$ for each $j$ (i.e. $|B_j| < \delta$), and
3. $m(F) + \varepsilon > \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} m(B_j)$.

In particular, note that $\{B_j\}$ is a $\delta$-cover of $F$.  But then we have
\begin{align}
m(F) + \varepsilon
  &> \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} m(B_j) \tag{by (3), above} \\
  &= c_n \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} r_j^n \\
  &\ge c_n \inf\left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{n} |U_j|^n : \text{$\{U_j\}$ is a $\delta$-cover of $F$} \right\} \\
  &= c_n \mathcal{H}^{n}_{\delta}(F).
\end{align}
Since $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ were arbitrary, it follows that we can take limits in order to obtain
\begin{align} \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \left(\lim_{\delta\to 0} m(F)\right) \ge \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \left(\lim_{\delta\to 0} c_n \mathcal{H}^{n}_{\delta}(F)\right)
&\implies \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \left( m(F) + \varepsilon \right) \ge c_n \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \mathcal{H}^n(F) \\
&\implies m(F) \ge c_n \mathcal{H}^n(F). \end{align}
This gives the opposite inequality, and finishes the proof.